# If we copy-paste the universe, would it follow the same trajectory?

Tags: universe, determinism

If we would copy-paste the universe in a single instant, would they follow the same trajectory? If yes. would this mean that the trajectory of our universe (and our self) is set in stone? If no. What would make it differ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot tell from current experiments. It depends on the nature of quantum mechanics. Are quantum mechanical results truly random? The standard Copenhagen interpretation would say yes, but other interpretations would disagree. The problem of the right interpretation is still open. By "copy-pasting" the universe it is unclear if you copy also all the possible outcomes or some hidden variables that decide the results of quantum experiments.

Any small difference in outcomes at the quantum level may lead to significant differences with respect to the original universe due to chaos.